# 'reset' Doesn't Clear The Terminal In Windows Subsystem For Linux

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Debian (stretch) in the Windows Subsystem For Linux. In bonified Linux installations, this will clear the backlog of the terminal window, but does not work in this environment. Is there a way to clear the terminal window in Windows Subsystem For Linux?

Comment: `reset` reinitialize terminal. You have to use `clear` instead. *man clear*: `clear  clears  your  screen  if  this is possible, including its scrollback buffer `

Comment: @Alex: But clearing the screen buffer sounds like what a reset _would do_, no?

Comment: @grawity Yes, `reset` should clear screen as well scrollback buffer on natively running Debian distro, but for some reason it doesn't behave the same on WSL, while `clear` still works

Comment: This works: `clear; clear`. And remember WSL IS NOT real Linux.